# Keep the option selected in search form - Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have a search form that searches for responsible, date and device name. When someone searches for a resposible with a date, I want that search data to be maintained in the result

The entire search form

```
  {{ Form::open(['route' => 'reviews.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'form-inline pull-right']) }}
  @csrf
  {{ Form::text('device_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre Equipo'])}}

  <select name="name">
          <option></option>
          <option>OK</option>
          <option>NOK</option>
  </select>

  {{ Form::date('created_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Creacion'])}}
  <select name="responsable">
          <option ></option>
      @foreach($users as $user)
          <option>{!! $user->name !!}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
  <button style="border: none;padding: 4px 20px;background-color: #d61628;color: white">Buscar</button>
  <button style="border: none;padding: 4px 20px;background-color: #d61628;color: white"><a href="{{route('reviews.index')}}">Reset</a></button>
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

And the index method in Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $responsable  = $request->get('responsable');
    $created_at  = $request->get('created_at');
    $device_name  = $request->get('device_name');

    $name = $request->get('name');

    $devices = Device::all();
    $reviews = Review::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->responsable($responsable)
        ->created_at($created_at)
        ->device_name($device_name)
        ->name($name)
        ->paginate(30);
    $users = User::all();
    return view('reviews.index', compact('devices', 'reviews', 'users'));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to state more clearly your goal with the select combo?

Comment: Of course, you see, I have a search form that searches for responsible, date and device name. When someone searches for a resposible with a date, I want that search data to be maintained in the result, to search with another person responsible and the same previous date, for example

Comment: Looks like what you want to do is to re-populate the form with the old values, so your select combo always get reset after submission. Right?

Comment: Exactically, that's happen

Comment: Can you post your routes (get form and post form) and your search method?

Comment: Done, I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `old()` function for re-populate the form with the last submitted data.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

So, in your blade code it would be something like this:

```
{{ Form::text('device_name', old('device_name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre Equipo'])}}

//...

{{ Form::date('created_at', old('created_at'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Creacion'])}}
```

For select, it's different, basically you compare each rendered option in the loop and if it's the one submitted you mark it as selected with html.

```
<select name="responsable">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user->name }}" {{ old('responsable') == $user->name ? 'selected' : '' }}>{!! $user->name !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Also, consider that `old()` also accepts a second parameter for default value in case you don't want it to be just *null*.